# Avoiding multiple Apache redirects for multiple rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have a need to put some redirects in place to enforce some rules and handle some URL changes.

Specifically as follows:

1. If the protocol is `http`, enforce `https`
2. If there is no subdomain or the subdomain is not `www`, enforce `www`
3. If the domain is `www.domainA.com` and the path does not **begin** with `/en/`, `/fr/`, `/de/` or `/es/`, enforce `/en/`
4. If the domain is `www.domainB.com` and the path does not **begin** with `/b_en/`, `/b_fr/`, `/b_de/` or `/b_es/`, enforce `/b_en/`

I've been trying to get this working so that only one 301 happens at any one time and we don't end up with a chain of 301s. For example a request to `http://domainA.com` could potentially be redirected 3 times:

1. `http://domainA.com` 301 to...
2. `https://domainA.com` 301 to...
3. `https://www.domainA.com` 301 to...
4. `https://www.domainA.com/en/`

However I've not been able to come with a solution.

This would live in a `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Only domainA and domainB can be used for this htaccess ? Because it is easier to test www or no subdomain, with domain names...

Comment: Yes this particular use case requires specific handling for points 3 and 4 in my requirements list above.

Comment: I understood that. But 1 and 2 only with the same and only 2 domains ?

Comment: Yes, requirement #1 and #2 are generic to both domains and there are only two domains in total.

Comment: Yes, but ideally that would include the path too, otherwise we end up with more than 1 redirect

Answer (score 1):

You can use in your `.htaccess`:

```
# domainA
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domainA\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(?:en|fr|de|es) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domainA.com/en%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

# domainB
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domainB\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/b_(?:en|fr|de|es) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domainB.com/b_en%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

# https & www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (?:^|\.)(domainA\.com|domainB\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Never more than one redirection.